# Shall i learn zend if i want to become magento 2 extension developer

Tags: magento-2.1, zend-framework, laravel-framework

I am a front end developer and worked on many wordpress,magento and shopify stores . But now i want to become real developer . I mean i want to prepare myself so i can develop magento 2 extensions from scratch.

As magento 2 is Zend based. Can you please suggest if somebody want to become good developer of magento 2 then is it mandatory to learn zend first ?

Because during extension development MVC of zend will be followed so i have this question.

Apart from this i am looking to learn one framework of php. I see codeignitor is easy to learn but neither we can develop shopify apps nor magento 2 modules so wanted to select between Zend and laravel.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Learning Zend framework is not mandatory to become a Magento 2 Extension Developer. Though within the Magento 2 codebase some zend libraries are used, we don't have to deal with it directly. Start with the below tutorial series for best understanding.

https://alanstorm.com/category/magento-2/#magento-2-mvc

If you want to learn a PHP framework start with Laravel that is easy to learn.

Comment: Thank you for your reply buddy ! 

Just one more query . Shall i go with codeigniter or Laravel ?

Comment: Personally you can go with your choice (codeigniter or laravel). But I would suggest to go with Laravel as it is used for building enterprise level applications and job prospects is also high.